# How to display HasMany relationship in Ember

Tags: ember.js

What is required to make this simple [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TrevTheDev/anM35/1/) display a list of categories with products e.g.

- vegetable

  - carrot
  - asparagus

View code:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="categories">
    {{#each}}
        <div>Category: {{name}}</div>
            {{#each product in this.products}}
                <div>Product: {{product.name}}</div>            
            {{/each}}
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

Model code:

```
App.Category = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    products: DS.hasMany('product')
});

App.Product = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string')
});
```

Route:

```
App.CategoriesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        return this.store.find('category');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the relationship async and fix the json (remove the id)

async because the records aren't included with the Category

no appended id because that's not the format Ember Data expects https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md

```
App.Category = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    products: DS.hasMany('product', {async: true})
});

App.Category.FIXTURES = [
    {    id: 1,    name: 'Shirts',   products: [1]},
    {    id: 2,    name: 'Pants',    products: [1,2]},
    {    id: 3,    name: 'Socks',    products: [3]},
    {    id: 4,    name: 'Shoes',    products: [3,4]}
];
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2Mguy/

Comment: Thanks you kingpin2k that is much appreciated!

Comment: Thanks for the link to the transition doco - that is most useful!

Comment: No prob, it's probably the most useful doc I've read on Ember Data as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fully functional [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3629u/1/) that demonstrates how to do this.

One of the other answers pointed out that you needed to add `{ async: true }` to the `hasMany` relationship, and remove `Ids` from `products`.

This is true, however, it doesn't fix all your rendering issues. You also need to change your default route to:

```
App.Router.map(function () {
    this.route('categories', { path: "/" });
});
```

Then, create a `CategoriesController` extending [Ember.ArrayController](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayController.html), with `itemController` set to 'category'. (See the Ember docs for more details) You can then create a `CategoryController` extending [Ember.ObjectController](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ObjectController.html).

Finally, update your `#each` statement to look like this:

```
{{#each category in controller}}
```

Again, here's the [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3629u/1/) demonstrating how this works.

Comment: Hi Daniel, the other things aren't necessary.  The array controller will be generated on it's own, and the item controller is only necessary if you want to add logic to each item (that doesn't exist on the model).  His route is a standard practice as well, having the `categories` being a resource (since it's a resource), not a route underneath application.

Comment: Interesting. If Ember creates these controllers automatically, why doesn't your JSFiddle render all the products?

Comment: when you navigate to the categories route (click categories) it does.  Are you seeing something different?

Comment: Ah, I see. I thought he wanted the categories route to be the default route.

Answer (score -1):

Simple `"How To"` with `Ruby on Rails 4`:

-app/serializers/list_serializer.rb

```
class ListSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  embed :ids, include: true

  attributes :id, :name
  has_many :tasks
end
```

-app/serializers/task_serializer.rb

```
class TaskSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :description, :list_id
end
```

-app/javascripts/models/task.js

```
EmTasks.Task = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  description: DS.attr("string"),
  list: DS.belongsTo('list')
});
```

-app/javascripts/models/list.js

```
EmTasks.List = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  tasks: DS.hasMany('task')
});
```

Sample List controller:

```
class ListsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def index
    respond_with List.all
  end
# ...
```

Then you will get `JSON` response for standard REST JSON API (`/lists.json`):

```
{
  lists: [
    {
      id: 15,
      name: "icebox",
      task_ids: [
        1
      ]
    }
  ],
  tasks: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "whatever",
      description: "",
      list_id: 15
    }
  ]
}
```

And you can print it in `handlebars` template:

```
  {{#each task in this.tasks}}
    {{task.name}}
  {{/each }}
```