# Emberjs How to Access DS.PromiseArray from each loop

Tags: ember.js, model, fixtures

[**Current Issue**](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/sepezezo/2/edit)
So from the link about I have been working with ember Fixture. And previously I was getting an error :
ember cannot set property 'store'
I didn't find much of anything on dealing with that issue in FIXTURES. but safe to say I no longer have that issue. And for folks that stumble upon this looking for an answer to that error I recommend checking your Fixure[{}] and make sure everything has an 'id', and carefully look for conflicts between that and your DS.Model.

OK so the problem at hand. I'm asking my product fixture to include all the images that are in a product. since the product hasMany images. But when i add {{image}} in my each statement it will display as:

```
<DS.PromiseArray:ember399>
```

And then if I also print a property that belongsTo another it will also return some funky stuff {{category}} returns:

```
<App.ProductCategory:ember395:1>(although it does spit out the 1 which is correct)
```

The properties that are a part of the product module display just fine so if I type {{color}} then all the colors will display.

I hope figuring out how to traverse through the object can help many folks out that may deal with this issue.
[**Current Issue**](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/sepezezo/2/edit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is a more complex repeat of a simple question that has already been answered on stack overflow:

[How to display HasMany relationship in Ember](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21177320/how-to-display-hasmany-relationship-in-ember)

To display the promise required another each loop inside the current loop.
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/sepezezo/2/edit